# Increase precision on a double variable for small numbers

Tags: c, double, precision

I'm trying to perform the following operation:

```
double exponent = pow(2.0, -254)
```

The result I get is 'inf', the actual result is: 3.4544e-77, which is a very small number, I would guess that I could get '0' instead but I get 'inf'.

I need the actual result, is there a way to improve precision on a double? I have tried also long double without success.

I'm programming on C with Visual Studio.

Comment: No, there is no way to improve the precision of `double`. There is a way to perform calculations and representing data differently, so it would match your requirements.

Comment: Your compiler might implement "long double".

Comment: If a `double` is IEEE754 double precision, it should support exponents of +/- 1023.  If I print with `%e` I get 3.454467e-77.  How are you printing the result?

Comment: Im evaluating the value on debug window, but if I use printf(%e, exponent) it will print 'inf'

Comment: Did you include math.h?

Comment: The problem is almost certainly not `pow` or how floating point works, but some technical problem in your code, like wrong type (ints instead of doubles). Show the actual code.

Comment: If you get infinity for `pow(2.0, -254)`, there is an error in your source code.

Comment: there is no source code, just that line, I need a variable to hold the result of operation '2^(-254)', Im including math.h and pow comes from that library so how can my source code be bad?

Comment: Please update your question with a complete piece of code that others can compile that reproduces the problem.  In other words, a [mcve].

Comment: There cannot be no source code. That line is source code. It is part of a program. Show the entire program. If it is large, reduce it to just the part that reproduces the problem. then show that.

Comment: If you are evaluating an expression in the debug window, then show **exactly** the text you typed into the debug window. It was not “printf(%e, exponent)”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, you can multiply by powers of two with `scalb`, so `scalb(1, -254)` is 2<sup>−254</sup>. You can also use powers of two in hexadecimal floating-point constants; 2<sup>−254</sup> is `0x1p-254`.

However, `pow(2.0, -254)` does not return infinity. If you attempted to print the return value, and “inf” was printed, there is an error in your source code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem was in my source code, my original code is:

```
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
    unsigned int scale = 1;
    unsigned int bias = 255;

    double temp = pow(2.0, scale - bias);

    printf("Number is: %e\n", temp);
    return;
}
```

which Im guessing the operation 'scale-bias' is overflowing since they are UINTS, thus getting me a 'inf', changing them to INT solves the issue:

```
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
    int scale = 1;
    int bias = 255;

    double temp = pow(2.0, scale - bias);

    printf("Number is: %e\n", temp);
    return;
}
```